# Help on negative numbers in an if statement

Tags: shell-script, xrandr

I am writing a script to automatically rotate the screen using a laptop's built-in accelerometer. Currently rotating the laptop in one way works, (and it also goes back to normal when putting it back how you normally use a laptop). I need to also do rotation for turning the laptop the other way. Here is my code:

```
#Read the accelerometer data
ACCEL=$(cut -d "," -f 2 /sys/devices/platform/lis3lv02d/position) 

if (($ACCEL > 700 ))
then 
   echo right
   xrandr --output LVDS --rotate right  # Rotate screen right
   exit
elif (($ACCEL < 300 ))
then
   echo normal
   xrandr --output LVDS --rotate normal  # Rotate screen normal
fi
```

As you can see, I have added code for positive numbers from the accelerometer.  Now I need to do the same thing for negative numbers (-700 instead of 700 and -300 instead of 300).

Comment: Negative numbers would be less than 300; can you explain the situations you want to cover?

Comment: If the accelerometer is -300 or higher (like 100) make the screen rotate the normal.If it is smaller than -700 (like -900) rotate the screen left.As you can see in the code I have already done it for the non negative number and it works (rotating the laptop turns the screen like on a phone but only only one way since I have not finished the negative code)

Comment: In line #1, the `<<< cat` is probably not necessary, i.e. this would be better:  `ACCEL=$(cut -d "," -f 2 /sys/devices/platform/lis3lv02d/position)`

Comment: @agc Then you edit the post

Comment: Suici, you're able to edit your own post as well.

Comment: Yes , I can edit it